# starting and stopping two functions with timeouts using two buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have two functions, `x()` and `y(), both of them called by clicking their buttons, *buttonX* and *buttonY*, and the actual action called on timeout. What I want to achieve:

1. When *buttonX* is clicked, function`y()` does not execute any longer, and function `x()` is called - with timeout;
2. When *buttonY* is clicked, function `x()` does not execute any longer, and function `y()` is called - with timeout;

How to do so?

**HTML**

```
<button onclick = "x()">button1</button>  
<button onclick = "y()">button2</button>
```

**JS**

```
function x(){
  // dosomething;  
  // stop execution of y()   
  setTimeout(x,2000);  
}
                    }  
function y(){
  // dosomeother thing;  
  // stop execution of x()  
  setTimeout(y,2000);
}
```

Comment: please add the code, you have and have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: Try setting a variable `timeoutX = setTimeout()` then you can cancel it by calling `clearTimeout(timeoutX)`. The same can be done for timeoutY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it by conditioning both actions within a timeout on some booleans, i.e.:

**HTML**

```
<button id="firstFunction">Run first function</button>
<button id="secondFunction">Run second function</button>
```

**JS**

```
var callFirstFunction = true;
var callSecondFunction = true;

document.getElementById("firstFunction").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  callFirstFunction = true;
  callSecondFunction = false;
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(callFirstFunction) {
      //your first function action
    }
  }, 10000);
}

document.getElementById("secondFunction").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  callSecondFunction = true;
  callFirstFunction = false;
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(callSecondFunction) {
      //your second function action
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it using the `clearTimeout` function. It is a little cleaner than using if statements in the callback function itself because the callback function gets canceled altogether.

```js
var timeoutOne;
var timeoutTwo;

function x(){
  clearTimeout(timeoutTwo);
  timeoutOne = setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Button One Pressed");        
  }, 1000);
}

function y(){
  clearTimeout(timeoutOne);
  timeoutTwo = setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Button Two Pressed");        
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="x()">Button One</button>  
<button onClick="y()">Button Two</button>
```